# python-twitter exception handling

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, python-twitter

Im trying to handle errors with Python-Twitter, for example: when I do the below passing a Twitter account that returns a 404 I get the following response...

```
import twitter

# API connection
api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='...',
              consumer_secret='...',
              access_token_key='...',
              access_token_secret='...')



try:
    data = api.GetUser(screen_name='repcorrinebrown')
Except Exception as err:
    print(err)
```

Response:

```
twitter.error.TwitterError: [{'code': 50, 'message': 'User not found.'}]
```

how can I iterate through this list on Except

Answer (score 9):

The [`message` property](https://github.com/bear/python-twitter/blob/master/twitter/error.py#L8) of the exception object should hold the data you are looking for. Try this:

```
import twitter

# API connection
api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='...',
              consumer_secret='...',
              access_token_key='...',
              access_token_secret='...')



try:
    data = api.GetUser(screen_name='repcorrinebrown')
except Exception as err:
    print(err.message)
    for i in err.message:
        print(i)
```

However, you may want to except the specific exception rather than all exceptions:

```
except twitter.error.TwitterError as err:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

For a more specific exception, I would use twitter.TweepError like this

```
try:
    user = api.get_user('user_handle')

except twitter.TweepError as error: #Speficically twitter errors
    print(error)
```